# Too large KL-divergence in training

Tags: bayesian, optimization, bayesian-network, kullback-leibler

I tried to train bayesian network using ELBO loss function.
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}(D, \theta) = KL[q(w|\theta)||P(w)] - \mathbb{E}_{q(w|\theta)}[\log p(D|w)]
\end{align*}

My question is, if model gets larger, is there any possibility to KL-divergence becomes larger so that dominate likelihood cost term? For large network, $w$ has many components, and their KL-divergence will be added as $\log$ is additive. But, likelihood loss does not change even we have larger network.

So, when model gets larger, KL-divergence term in ELBO will be dominated. So I think model will be trained so that it just only regularize, but not do indeed train to increase accuracy.

Indeed, in my implementation, my model has 2 hidden layer as bayesian. But it cannot be trained well. When I debug, cross entropy loss is up to $200$, but my KL-divergence is up to $30000$. So my network is only at first trained to increase accuracy, but after some epochs, its accuracy becomes lower. Is there any wrong in my opinion or my code implementation?

```
def forward(self, x): # part of Bayesian Linear layer
    # Sample w, b
    w_eps = torch.randn((self.in_features, self.out_features))
    b_eps = torch.randn(self.out_features)
    w_std = torch.exp(0.5 * self.w_logvar)
    b_std = torch.exp(0.5 * self.b_logvar)
    w = self.w_mu + w_std * w_eps
    b = self.b_mu + b_std * b_eps

    # Evaluate KL-divergence loss
    self.posterior = (-math.log(math.sqrt(2*math.pi))-torch.log(w_std+1e-8) -(((w-self.w_mu)**2) / (2 * w_std**2+1e-8))).sum() \
                    + (-math.log(math.sqrt(2*math.pi))-torch.log(b_std+1e-8) -(((b-self.b_mu)**2) / (2 * b_std**2+1e-8))).sum()
    
    self.prior = (-math.log(math.sqrt(2*math.pi))-(0.5 * w**2)).sum() \
                    + (-math.log(math.sqrt(2*math.pi))-(0.5 * b**2)).sum()
    self.kl_loss = self.posterior - self.prior
     
    return torch.mm(x,w) + b

class BayesianNet(nn.Module):

"""
2 layer Fully connected Network
Linear -> ReLU -> Linear -> ReLU -> Linear
"""

def __init__(self, mode, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    
    super(BayesianNet, self).__init__()
    self.mode = mode
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten() # 2D to 1D array
    self.hidden1 = BayesianLinear(in_features=input_size, out_features=hidden_size[0], mixture_prior=mixture_prior, prior_init=prior_init)
    self.hidden2 = BayesianLinear(in_features=hidden_size[0], out_features=hidden_size[1], mixture_prior=mixture_prior, prior_init=prior_init)
    self.out = BayesianLinear(in_features=hidden_size[1], out_features=output_size, mixture_prior=mixture_prior, prior_init=prior_init)
    if mode == "Classification":
        self.last = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='sum')
    elif mode == "Regression":
        self.last = nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
    

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = F.relu(self.hidden1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.hidden2(x))
    x = self.out(x)
    return x

def kl_loss(self):
    return self.hidden1.kl_loss + self.hidden2.kl_loss + self.out.kl_loss

def loss(self, x, y, samples=1):
    kl_loss = torch.zeros(samples)
    nll = torch.zeros(samples)
    for i in range(samples):
        pred = self.forward(x)
        kl_loss[i] = self.kl_loss() / 600 # I run MNIST with batch size 100, so total 600 batch exist
        nll[i] = self.last(pred, y)
    return pred, (kl_loss.mean() + nll.mean())/x.shape[0]
```